# What is the proper configuration for haproxy to connect to a remote server via a corporate proxy?

Tags: haproxy, http-proxy

We have configured haproxy at our environment.
Front end is configured with localhost with port and backend is configured with some server ip(which is in internet) and port. For that backend server there is no direct access , it has to goes through corporate proxy server.
That corporate proxy detail is added in environment variable as http_proxy. What should be the configuration in haproxy...

Somewhere i found found like use send-proxy , tried with that in backend . But still it's not connecting to corporate proxy server.